# Write something in cell with UDF while executed

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I'm writing a UDF that gets data from a website with many attempts so it might take a while (10 seconds top) to calculate. The problem is that Excel freezes until the UDF is fully calculated.

I'd like to write "Retrieving data..." in the calling cell while the data is downloaded and processed without hanging Excel. And once the function ends, change the text to the result.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: The function would have to finish. It would be like starting to type in a cell, nothing else will happen until you have pressed enter.

Answer (score 7):

Assume the following UDF in a public module code sheet.

```
Function retrievingData()
    Dim i As Long, t As Double
    For i = 1 To 2
        'Debug.Print i
        t = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
        Do While Now < t
            DoEvents
        Loop
    Next i
    retrievingData = 99
End Function
```

Next, create a conditional formatting rule in A2 based upon the following formula.

```
=not(a2)
```

Click Format and assign a custom number format of,

```
"Retrieving data..."
```

Finally, put the UDF into A2.

```
=retrievingData()
```

Caveat: you might need several DoEvents loops to get your own UDF running properly. Each one will slow things down.

[image]

Comment: Nice, but the UDFs are in a XLAM file, so It must be achieved with code.

Comment: Nice of you mention that beforehand. However, still not impossible if you think about it.

Comment: @Jeeped, it's not fair to say that he didn't mention that beforehand since he specifically asked for a way to write the cell with an UDF. Note that even with `DoEvent`, cell calculation and other UDF won't be running until the function returns which mean that Excel will still be partially frozen. A more reliable approach would be to use events or a timer.

Comment: No, I maintain this method is still viable.