# placeholder in cell with UDF while calculating

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write "loading" when user enters function (UDF) in a cell. It takes time for UDF to perform calculations so "loading" would instruct user to wait. I found the solution in the link below but it's a manual step, I want to do this within UDF as UDF is in a XLAM (add-in) file.

[Write something in cell with UDF while executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320989/write-something-in-cell-with-udf-while-executed)

```
Function retrievingData()
    Dim i As Long, t As Double
    For i = 1 To 2
        'Debug.Print i
        t = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
        Do While Now < t
            DoEvents
        Loop
    Next i
    retrievingData = 99
End Function
```

"loading" should be displayed in the cell of the UDF

Comment: should "loading" be displayed in the cell of the UDF or would a pop-up/UI (for the duration of the loading process)I of some sort suffice.

Comment: "loading" should be displayed in the cell of the UDF